# Let's say we had a sack with exactly 4 green marbles, 4 orange marbles, 4 black marbles and 4 violet marbles.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many different picks are there having exactly 8 marbles that have at least one marble of each color?

I'm not quite sure whether this is a permutation or a combination. Going with the assumption that it is a combination I'm guessing the sample space is $\binom{16}{8}$ . To find at least one marble of each color we could go with the complement of this statement. Not quite sure how to express it.

Perhaps $\binom{16}{8}$ $-4 \binom{12}{4}$ with the assumption that the complement of "at least one of each color" could be expressed as $-4\binom{12}{4}$ But even that seems lacking.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also, add detail to explain what you mean by an "alternate pick".

Comment: @lulu by alternate I meant different. I've changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: Alternatively: What is the cardinality of the set $\{(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4)\mid 0\leq m_i\leq 4, \sum_i m_i=8\}$? If you remove the condition $m_i\leq 4$, there is a well known formula.

Comment: Ok.  But you should still edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Do you consider the order of marbles to be important?

Comment: @Levent $1\leq m_i$ here instead of $0\leq m_i$, but otherwise yes... I expect this is an exercise meant to practice stars-and-bars

Comment: As an aside... "*sample space*"... "*probability*"... The question is worded as asking how many ways such and such can be done.  It is not a probability question and does not deserve any related tags or references to probability specific questions about this until we were explicitly asked to do so.  If you do not know whether order matters or not, I would recommend assuming it does not as that is the far more common problem to concern ourselves with.  Similarly, if you do not know if each marble is uniquely identifiable, I would recommend assuming that all marbles are identical except by color

Comment: @Jmoravitz I've been contemplating the order for a while and lean towards it not being important. Hence a combination.

Comment: In doing so, this becomes a question of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), a standard problem type.  The twist for this one is that we are limited by the number of each color available.  Ignoring that limit for now, the answer is immediate using the link provided.  To account for that limitation, consider how many outcomes we counted were "bad" because we used five or more of a particular color.  Note that thankfully we cannot have used too many of two colors at the same time, but in more complicated problems we might need inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: If you really *are* interested in the probability... then be warned that outcomes counted by stars-and-bars are not equally likely outcomes.  For the probability question instead, you will do well to approach via inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Not interested in the probability at this point @JMoravitz . Merely having the number of different ways to express the problem above would be sufficient.

Comment: @lulu hope the edits are slightly better now.

Comment: The body of the question should contain the entire question, and not rely on the question title. Also, it's "complement", not "compliment".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming order does not matter and each marble were uniquely identifiable, approach by inclusion-exclusion, getting rid of the "bad" outcomes which were missing one or more colors.  We start with the total number of ways to pick, then subtracting those ways where at least one color was missing, adding back in the ways where two colors were missing.

$$\binom{16}{8}-4\binom{12}{8}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{8}$$

This answer which uses marbles as all distinct is the most likely answer to be helpful when answering the related probability question under the most common assumptions about distribution and such, the probability being this answer divided by $\binom{16}{8}$.

---

The more likely question if we were purely concerned with practicing our counting skills is where order does not matter and marbles are all identical except perhaps by color.  For this, we use stars-and-bars.

Relate your problem to the problem of counting the number of integer solutions to the system $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=8 \\1\leq x_i\leq 4~~\forall i\end{cases}$

By ignoring the upperlimit, this becomes a question of stars-and-bars.  We imagine laying out eight stars in a row and then simultaneously choosing three of the available gaps between the stars to place bars having not repeated a choice and interpreting the result as an arrangement we are interested in (*or interpreting as a solution to the linear system above*).  The stars to the left of the first bar will correspond to the number of marbles of the first color we used.  The stars between the first and second bar will correspond to the number of marbles of the second color we used etc...

There are seven available gaps and we want to choose three of them so there are $\binom{7}{3}$ different ways to pick marbles here.

Now we take into consideration the upper bounds... some of these ways we counted were bad because we used more marbles than were possible for a color.  In this problem we see that the only way to have picked eight marbles with more than four marbles of a color while also having at least one of every marble would be if we picked exactly five marbles of a color and one marble of each of the others.  There are thus exactly four "bad" outcomes we counted.

$$\binom{7}{3}-4$$

To emphasize again, the outcomes counted by stars-and-bars will generally not be equally likely (*unless the problem explicitly states otherwise*) and so this is generally unhelpful for most probability questions.  Also, as problems get more complicated, there may have been greater challenges here at the last step in counting how many outcomes were bad.  For the general approach, you may need to repeat the stars-and-bars argument multiple times having performed some algebraic manipulations or changes of variable and iterated through a more full inclusion-exclusion argument.  For more on that, search elsewhere on this site for larger examples.

Note also the use of stars-and-bars for solving systems.  The number of solutions to the system $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_a = b\\0\leq x_i\end{cases}$ will be $\binom{a+b-1}{a-1}$

The number of solutions to the system $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2\dots+x_a = b\\1\leq x_i\end{cases}$ will be $\binom{b-1}{a-1}$

Be warned that some books will write the above system where the number of variables is $n$ and they sum to $r$.  Other authors may write it where the number of variables is instead $r$ and they sum to $n$.  This can lead to some confusion in whether you were meant to use $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ or if you were meant to use $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$.  If you remember the derivation and where the formula comes from in the first place, you should be able to keep it straight in your head.

Comment: (+1) It makes me very happy when an answer mentions that the stars-and-bars method is not what you want for the probability question - because I am currently teaching probability from a textbook that completely fails to mention this!

Comment: @MishaLavrov quite.  As a short illustrative point, using stars and bars we find there are three outcomes when flipping two coins.  We either wound up with both as heads, both as tails, or one of each.  The probability of both being heads however is not $\frac{1}{3}$ despite there being three possible outcomes.